# How can I trace executable files and perform bash command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have a quite specific problem. I have a folder and subfolders where I have executable files (meaning no extension). I am using Linux and I am just trying to copy all of the shared object files that are required by the executables. In Linux, you can simply type `ldd PATH_TO_EXEC` and it will give you all of the shared objects which are run during the runtime.

First of all, I have tried using this:

```
import os
import subprocess

path_to_libs = "/home/a/master-wheel/ros_ws/devel/lib/"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_libs):
        for dir in dirs:
            for file in files:
                libs = subprocess.check_output(['ldd', path_to_libs + '/' + file])
                libs = libs.decode('utf-8')
                for lib in libs.split():
                    if lib[0] == '/' and lib[1] != 'o' and lib[1] != 'h':
                        subprocess.run(['cp', lib, '/home/a/master-wheel/binaries/'])
```

The problem is that `file` does not count executables as files and therefore this code just returns nothing and thinks that no files exist.

Then, I tried something uglier:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_libs):
    for dir in dirs:
        try:
            print("PATH: " + path_to_libs + dir + '/*')
            libs = subprocess.call(['ldd', path_to_libs + dir + '/*'])
            libs = libs.decode('utf-8')
            print(libs)
            for lib in libs.split():
                if lib[0] == '/' and lib[1] != 'o' and lib[1] != 'h':
                    print(lib)
        except:
            continue
```

And the `libs = subprocess.call(['ldd', '/home/a/master-wheel/ros_ws/devel/lib/uwb_server/*'])` gives me an error `ldd: /home/a/master-wheel/ros_ws/devel/lib/uwb_server/*: No such file or directory` for all folders even though if I type the same command on a terminal, I get a fine result.

What can I do here?

Comment: `*`-expansion is done by the shell. So it isn't happening when you call the command directly. Consider using `glob` to do that

Comment: @rdas You mean call glob to store all files and then call the subprocess one by one? Does glob see executables?

Comment: `glob` can expand the `*` for you.

Comment: @rdas Yes, works well